# Android custom View appears intermittently in ListView row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view

I have a custom View that I want to be square. When included in a ListView row, it should fill 100% of the row height, and set its width to be the same as its height.

To do so I have overridden `onMeasure()`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
     int parentHeight = ((View) this.getParent()).getHeight();
     setMeasuredDimension(parentHeight, parentHeight);
}
```

In my XML file for my list row I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="number" />


    <SquareView
        android:id="@+id/square_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/number"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, the SquareView only appears intermittently, most notably when I start scrolling the list.

I can't see any circular dependency in my XML file. My guess is that sometimes the height of the RelativeLayout must be returning 0, thus causing the SquareView to set its own height and width to 0. Other times the RelativeLayout returns its actual height, thus causing the SquareView to appear.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try `getMeasuredHeight()`, but you should take another approach in the `onMeasure()` method and actually look at the sizes and constraints passed in through `widthMeasureSpec` and  `heightMeasureSpec`. You should be calculating the width/height based on those values.

Comment: @Luksprog Unfortunately a change to `int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);` results in no SquareView appearing at all. Will see if a change to `int parentHeight = ((View) this.getParent()).getMeasuredHeight();` works. EDIT: no, the SquareView still only shows intermittently.

Comment: Are you sure this is related to the `SquareView` and not because some flawed logic in the `getView()` method of the adapter(like something there which modifies the `SquareView` without reverting those changes for other positions not requiring that change)?

Comment: @Luksprog The adapter is just a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and I haven't overridden its `getView()` method (or any other methods). I do access the `SquareView` in my `ViewBinder`: it calls `setColor(int color)` and `setNumber(float number)` on the `SquareView`, which affect the display (but not the size) of the `SquareView`. They both call `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()`. I don't see what would cause any issues there.

Comment: Check this `onMeasure()` method https://gist.github.com/luksprog/8803856 . See if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks - that code makes the SquareView fill the entire row's width (`widthMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` and `heightMode = MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`), and then sets the height to the same - so on my device I get a 720x720 square.

Comment: Then you need to make your row have a precise height if the entire width(with huge value 720) is not what you want(as you get UNSPECIFIED for the SquareView that means the RelativeLayout also gets an UNSPECIFIED height value). Even so you could simply add another `Math.min(...)` operation between the `actualSize`(resulted from `Math.min(width, height)`) and a default value(like half, a quarter etc of the screen) to prevent it from using huge values.

Comment: @Luksprog I've stuck a fixed height of 70dp as a quick fix for the moment. I'm not entirely satisfied with that as a solution as it can spoil the display of other `TextView`s in the row, for instance by horizontally cutting halfway through a line, so if you have any comments on how I could gracefully specify the row to be exactly as high as its TextView elements (without recoursing to WRAP_CONTENT, which leaves it UNSPECIFIED), I'd be interested. Thanks!

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to have a custom parent for those items, the `TextViews` and the square view. Then by measuring the `TextViews` first you could pass proper dimension values to the square view to be exactly as you want. Also, you didn't mention what that view does, if it's just for visual appearance you may just let the parent(again with a custom parent) draw the stuff knowing its exact size.